# Calculate the average of the messages for the new users in R?

Tags: r

could anyone help me solve this problem with R?
Imagine each id reads one message will be record in the data.  The following are the data:

```
    > data
   id       date
1    1 2015-10-01
2    2 2015-10-01
3    2 2015-10-01
4    3 2015-10-01
5    4 2015-10-01
6    4 2015-10-01
7    5 2015-10-02
8    1 2015-10-02
9    3 2015-10-02
10   4 2015-10-02
11   6 2015-10-02
12   6 2015-10-02
13   7 2015-10-02
14   7 2015-10-02
15   1 2015-10-03
16   8 2015-10-03
17   8 2015-10-03
18   7 2015-10-03
19   3 2015-10-03
20   9 2015-10-03
21   9 2015-10-03
22   1 2015-10-04
23   2 2015-10-04
24  10 2015-10-04
25  11 2015-10-04
26  11 2015-10-04
```

For example: id1 reads one message on the first day, id2 reads two messages on the second day, and so on.
what I need to calculate is the average of the messages for the ids which are new compared to the first day, like id5 ,id6 and id7 are the new ids comes from 2015-10-2, the total new messages for those three ids are 5 messages, so the average of message for the new users are 5/3.
The first day 2015-10-1's average is 6/4(6messages and 4 new ids).
I hope the result will showed like one dataframe which contains the variable of the number of the new users, and the number of the messages for the new user, and the average.

Comment: According to your data, `id 1` and `id 2` read 1 and 2 messages the same day (2015-10-01), respectively. And in your example, it `uid`, not `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `dplyr` approach. 
For each date it calculates the number of new users and how many messages those users read.

```
dt = read.table(text=
"uid       date
1    1 2015-10-01
2    2 2015-10-01
3    2 2015-10-01
4    3 2015-10-01
5    4 2015-10-01
6    4 2015-10-01
7    5 2015-10-02
8    1 2015-10-02
9    3 2015-10-02
10   4 2015-10-02
11   6 2015-10-02
12   6 2015-10-02
13   7 2015-10-02
14   7 2015-10-02
15   1 2015-10-03
16   8 2015-10-03
17   8 2015-10-03
18   7 2015-10-03
19   3 2015-10-03
20   9 2015-10-03
21   9 2015-10-03
22   1 2015-10-04
23   2 2015-10-04
24  10 2015-10-04
25  11 2015-10-04
26  11 2015-10-04", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# save date as date object
dt$date = ymd(dt$date)


data.frame(date = unique(dt$date)) %>%          ## get unique dates in your initial dataset
  group_by(date) %>%                            ## for each date
  do({new_ids = setdiff(unique(dt[dt$date == ymd(.$date),]$uid),   ## get unique new user ids
                        unique(dt[dt$date < ymd(.$date),]$uid))
      N_new_ids = length(new_ids)                                  ## count those new user ids
      N_msg = nrow(dt[dt$date == ymd(.$date) & dt$uid %in% new_ids,])   ## count number of messages the new users read
      data.frame(N_new_ids, N_msg)}) %>%                           ## create results
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Avg = N_msg/N_new_ids)                                    ## calculate average


#         date N_new_ids N_msg      Avg
#       (time)     (int) (int)    (dbl)
# 1 2015-10-01         4     6 1.500000
# 2 2015-10-02         3     5 1.666667
# 3 2015-10-03         2     4 2.000000
# 4 2015-10-04         2     3 1.500000
```

Comment: Thanks! I check it works. I'm too busy yesterday. Do you have any advise to help me to learn R quickly?

Comment: Not really a specific simple way to do that. Depends on the person and how much time you can spend per day. Just start using it a lot and experiment with your own (simulated) datasets. Create a dataset and give tasks to yourself to do. Data manipulation (joins, re-shaping, updating variables) and data analysis mainly.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a 'for' loop to solve this, if you don't want to bring in any new libraries.

1) Read the data

```
x<-read.table(text=
"uid       date
1    1 2015-10-01
2    2 2015-10-01
3    2 2015-10-01
4    3 2015-10-01
5    4 2015-10-01
6    4 2015-10-01
7    5 2015-10-02
8    1 2015-10-02
9    3 2015-10-02
10   4 2015-10-02
11   6 2015-10-02
12   6 2015-10-02
13   7 2015-10-02
14   7 2015-10-02
15   1 2015-10-03
16   8 2015-10-03
17   8 2015-10-03
18   7 2015-10-03
19   3 2015-10-03
20   9 2015-10-03
21   9 2015-10-03
22   1 2015-10-04
23   2 2015-10-04
24  10 2015-10-04
25  11 2015-10-04
26  11 2015-10-04", header=T)
```

You will need to know the start date to start the iteration with. Then for every new date, old users will be nothing but the users belonging to the earlier dates.

So for an iteration having new dates, subset the data such that you remove the old users. See the following code

```
#Get the start date and find all the unique dates available
start_date<-min(x$date)
uniq_date<-unique(x$date)

#Create variables which are required
#In our case the new data frame would just need no of new users, messages and average messages.
old_users<-numeric(0)
new_users<-numeric(0)
new_msgs<-numeric(0)
avg_msg<-numeric(0)

#Create the data frame with 0 rows and required columns
new_data<-data.frame(Date=character(0),users=numeric(0),msgs=numeric(0),msg=numeric(0))

#order the x based on x, so that they start with the start date
x<-x[order(x$date),]

for(i in 1:length(uniq_date))
{
        #Subset the data for a date and excluding old_users
        #For start_date, old_users is 'numeric(0)', i.e., no old users

        temp_subset<-x[x$date %in% uniq_date[i] & !x$uid %in% old_users,]

        #Calculating the required parameters for new data frame.
        new_users=length(unique(temp_subset$uid))
        new_msgs=nrow(temp_subset)
        avg_msg=new_msgs/new_users

        #Include the results of a particular date to the new data frame
        new_data<-rbind(new_data,data.frame(Date=uniq_date[i],users=new_users,msgs=new_msgs,avg=avg_msg))
        #When computation for a date is over, declare those ids as old_users
        old_users=c(old_users,unique(temp_subset$uid))
}
```

P.S. the code may seem lengthy but it is very simple to understand.